# Showing progress for vector operation

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am solving a complicate equation that includes a huge matrices size and many operations. Its in vector formula. It takes very long time to finish. So, I need to show which step is done on the screen. When we are using `loop` we can include counter inside it to show the steps that is done. For example, multiplying two matrices.

```
  clear;
  clc;
  a=rand(1,5);
  b=rand(1,5);
  c(1,:)=0;
  for i=1:5
    c(i)=a(i)*b(i);
    fprintf('%d\n ', i); 
  end
```

However, if we use vector to multiply two matrices this will be like

```
c=a.*b
```

Is there anyway that we can monitor the progress. So, we can show which step is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92075-how-do-i-monitor-the-progress-of-my-calculation-or-script-in-matlab):

> There is no built-in functionailty to perform this in MATLAB beyond specifying debug statements and print-to-screen updates at specific sections of the user's code.

Also, something like `waitbar` is not your solution, as you want to monitor the process of computation which is done by matlab, not yours.

Comment: Thank you. waitbar  as you mentioned is not useful here and it is working inside loop. I do not have loop